# Как в Django с помощью middleware реализовать проверку на количество запросов с одного IP?

Tags: python, django

Есть задача: добавьте middleware, которое будет возвращать ошибку если за последние n секунд было больше k запросов c одного ip адреса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможно, https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ вам поможет